# PHP Switch Case

Tags: php, nginx, switch-statement, php-7.1

I made a pretty stupid Logic Error in a very Basic **PHP** Script.

See u_mulders Answer for the Conclusion.

The Script accesses a $_GET[] Variable and should just determine if the Variable is set (which works) and if its set to a value above 0 (this is not working as expected).

Here comes the "switch.php" File:

```
<?php

if($_GET["variable"]==NULL){
    die('Set $_GET["variable"] to use this Script!');
}

//Create Instance of $_GET["variable"] casted to Integer
$variable = (integer)$_GET["variable"];

//this var_dump displays that the $variable is successfully casted to an Integer
var_dump($variable);

switch ($variable) {
    case ($variable > 0):
        echo "You entered $variable!";
        break;
    
    default:        
        echo "Either Your variable is less than 0, or not a Number!";
        break;
}

?>
```

Now I expected the first case-Statement to only run if $variable is greater than 0.

This is not the Case if I open the URL: http://www.someserver.com/switch.php?variable=0

The Output is as follows:

.../switch.php:11:int 0

You entered 0!

I hope You can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just change the $variable = (integer)$_GET["variable"]; to $variable = $_GET["variable"];. Because you are using explicit casting that's every time it change the variable value to integer either in char form as well

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using a switch with different expressions.  Use it for the same expression that has different values.  Read the docs to see the primary use case of a switch.  "The switch statement is similar to a series of IF statements on the **same expression**".  http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: I know that you use switch for value comparison and if´s for conditions. I just was to blind to see my logic error here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, `$variable` is `0`, case `$variable > 0` which is `0 > 0` is `false`.

Compare `0` and `false`. What do you get? Of course - true.

Rewrite your `switch` to:

```
// compare not `$variable` but result of some operation with `true`
switch (true) {           
    case ($variable > 0):
        echo "You entered $variable!";
        break;

    default:        
        echo "Either Your variable is less than 0, or not a Number!";
        break;
}
```

Comment: @abrar and this will help how?

Comment: Is right. It was just a stupid Logic Error. Comparing 0 to false wich is always true.

Comment: @u_mulder I think you should elaborate on `Compare 0 and false. What do you get? Of course - true.` otherwise this question is non-understandable. Something about PHP types and why 0 == false might help.

Comment: Loose comparisons with == http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood how does a switch works..

```
switch (VAR-TO-COMPARE){
    case VAL-TO-BE-COMOARED: do something
}
```

So what is going on in your script is you are comparing the integer value stored in $variable (0 in your example) with a Boolean value Wich is the result of the Boolean equation `$variable > 0`. 
Inside the case, your integer value is implicitly casted to Boolean TRUE value, so if you insert a number your switch will always go to the first case of your switch.

You can use an if statement Wich is both more readable and efficient

```
if ($variable > 0){
    do something
} else{
    do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use comparison operator in a switch case. Refer to the php manual. You can use if statement to do what you looking for.

```
if($variable > 0){
  echo "You entered $variable!";
}else{
  echo "Either Your variable is less than 0, or not a Number!";
}
```

Comment: Yes You can use comparison operators in switch/case. You probably shouldn't but You can.

Answer (score -1):

```
switch (true) {
    case ($variable > 0):
        echo "You entered $variable!";
        break;

    default:        
        echo "Either Your variable is less than 0, or not a Number!";
        break;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.